# Want To Save xslt applied xml file with changed node value 

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an XSLT for an XML and its node value is displayed as text.
Now I want to save the original XML file as a new file with the changed values. The values are entered by user in xml generated html textboxes.
I am using windows mobile(PDA) C# .net compact framework. 
Loading xslt applied xml file into webbrowser control.

Comment: Tried to make sense out of your question, but it still quite vague. Sorry, best I can do with the limited info.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

a. Load an XmlDocument from the XML file.

b. Load an XSLT document from the XSL file.

c. Create an XmlTextWriter or XmlWriter to which the output is written. This could reference the target XML file if the output method of the transformation is "xml".

d. Transform the XML document using the XSLT by providing any required parameters. I think these values would be sourced from your user entry textboxes.

[Here is a walkthrough](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322) that shows how to do it without even having to use an XmlTextWriter directly. And [another](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63).

Answer (score 1):

You give zero detail on your environment (programming language, operating system, etc). On Unix, with xsltproc, I would simply use shell redirection:

```
xsltproc transform.xsl data.xml > result.xml
```

Comment: I am using windows mobile(PDA) C# .net compact framework.
Loading xslt applied xml file into webbrowser control.

Comment: Edit your question to provide the details, no one will pay attention to a comment's comment.